# How to extend winrt control with generics

Tags: c#, xaml, generics, windows-runtime

I am trying to extend a Page control in a winrt application. The general idea is...

**MyControl.xaml:**

```
   <local:MyPage
      x:Class="MyControl"
      ..
   >
    ...
    ...
    ...
   </model:MyControl>
```

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
    public sealed partial class MyControl: MyPage<aModelClass>
    {
     ...
     ...
    }
```

**MyPage.cs:**

```
    public Class MyPage<T> : Page
    {    
    }
```

So,, my question is if it is possible to use generic in this way,,, and if so,, how??
I have found no way to handle the generic in the xaml file,, on the other side,, I have been unsuccesful to find anything on this question by googling.

Regards
/lg